# play-services-wearable:9.0.2 not working on Moto360 (2014)

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

play-services-wearable:9.0.2 not working on Moto360 (2014).
Whenever I have

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.2'
```

in my wearable dependencies, it does not get installed on the watch.
Using

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
```

everything works fine!
Anyone else observed the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your Google Play Services on the watch is out of date. When you open Settings > About > Versions on the watch, what does it show for Google Play Services? If it's less than 9.0.2, an app requiring that level won't install.

This version should sync from Google Play Services on your phone. You can check that from Settings > Apps on the phone (you may need to go to All Apps within there). You can also update it by going to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms, again on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, indeed the play services on the watch were not up to date.

After reading the above suggestion everything works like intended!